# Form a nested tree from an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

So there is array of objects of below format

```js
let inputs = [
    {
      "id": "614344d9d9c21c0001e6af2e",
      "groupName": "Unassigned",
      "parentGroup": "null"
    },
    {
      "id": "614447da152f69c3c1d52f2e",
      "groupName": "P1",
      "parentGroup": "null"
    },
    {
      "id": "614447da152f69c3c1d52f38",
      "groupName": "K1",
      "parentGroup": "C1"
    },
    {
      "id": "614447da152f69c3c1d52f3e",
      "groupName": "A2",
      "parentGroup": "C2"
    },
    {
      "id": "614447da152f69c3c1d52f40",
      "groupName": "G1",
      "parentGroup": "P2"
    },
    {
      "id": "614447da152f69c3c1d52f46",
      "groupName": "F1",
      "parentGroup": "null"
    },
    {
      "id": "614447da152f69c3c1d52f30",
      "groupName": "P2",
      "parentGroup": "null"
    },
    {
      "id": "614447da152f69c3c1d52f36",
      "groupName": "C2",
      "parentGroup": "P1"
    },
    
    {
        "id": "614447da152f69c3c1d52f3c",
        "groupName": "A1",
        "parentGroup": "C2"
      },
      {
        "id": "614447da152f69c3c1d52f34",
        "groupName": "C1",
        "parentGroup": "P1"
      },
      {
        "id": "614447da152f69c3c1d52f32",
        "groupName": "P3",
        "parentGroup": "null"
      },
      {
        "id": "614447da152f69c3c1d52f3a",
        "groupName": "K2",
        "parentGroup": "C1"
      },
      {
        "id": "614447da152f69c3c1d52f42",
        "groupName": "GG1",
        "parentGroup": "G1"
      },
      {
        "id": "614447da152f69c3c1d52f44",
        "groupName": "GGG1",
        "parentGroup": "GG1"
      }
  ]
```

i am trying to create a tree structure of format

```
{name:'p1',children:[{name:'c1':children:[]}]}
```

so i sorted all the elements of given array considering element with parentGroup as "null" to be at the top of the array.

```js
 let finalArr = [];
 inputs.sort((a,b)=> (a.parentGroup === "null") ? -1 : 1);
```

And for each element of the inputs array, i was iterating below logic

```js
inputs.forEach(ele => {
            if(ele.parentGroup === "null"){
             let child= {name:ele.groupName,children:[]};
             finalArr.push(child);
            }else{
              finalArr.forEach(item => {
                this.findNode(item,ele);
              })
            }
          });
```

If the 'parentGroup' of element is "null", then create a leaf kind of obj and push the element to 'finalArr' array

Else, then iterate across all the elements of 'finalArr' over a recursion function

```js
public findNode(ele, obj){
    if(ele.children.length === 0){
      if(ele.name === obj.parentGroup){
        let child = {name:obj.groupName, children:[]};
      ele.children.push(child);
      }
    }else{
      let j = ele.children.length-1;
      this.findNode(ele.children[j--],obj);
    }
  }
```

This recursion function will check the element has children or not, if no children, then compare the parentGroup of given obj, with name of element from 'FinalArr'.
if so ,push the current obj to the children of the element of finalArr.

else, that is, when children has more elements, the same recursion will be triggered until depth of the element is reached.

With this i tought i would make a tree structure with given inputs array, but when a parent has more children, of same level, this logic fails,
so the inputs array has 'c1' which is a child of 'p1', but nly the child 'c2' resides, not sure the what is that i missed.

[image]

Comment: please address only a single problem in this question. do you have a problem to get a tree data structure or to render the tree in html?

Comment: To get a tree  like data structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is how `finalArr` is used to generate the html elements.

When doing `console.log(finalArr)` it looks like the code block below. So it seems to me like the code you have to build the structure of `finalArr` is working fine.

```js
// console.log(finalArr)

[
  { "name": "P3", "children": [] },
  {
    "name": "P2",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "G1",
        "children": [
          { "name": "GG1", "children": [
              { "name": "GGG1", "children": [] }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  { "name": "F1", "children": [] },
  {
    "name": "P1",
    "children": [
      { "name": "C2", "children": [
          { "name": "A1", "children": [] }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  { "name": "Unassigned", "children": [] }
]
```

**EDIT**

As OP mentioned in the comment C1 was missing. I've introduced a root element that will have the `finalArr` as its children and changed the findNode to use a for loop instead of forEach. In this way we can also break when we find the node and not continue recursing.

As part of the initial sorting we will sort the inputs by `parentGroup` so we ensure that a childs parent is added in the tree structure before we try to find it with `findNode`.

I believe this produces the correct result:

```js
inputs.sort((a, b) => (a.parentGroup === "null" ? -1 : 1));

// Sort by parentGroup
let root = inputs.pop();
let inputsDescending = [root];
let max = inputs.length * inputs.length;
let c = 0;
while (inputs.length > 0 && max > c) {
  const child = inputs.pop();
  const hasParentGroup = inputsDescending.find(
    (parent) => parent.groupName === child.parentGroup
  );
  if (hasParentGroup || child.parentGroup === "null") {
    inputsDescending.push(child);
  } else {
    inputs.unshift(child);
  }
}

let rootEle = { name: "root", children: [] };

inputsDescending.forEach((obj) => {
  if (obj.parentGroup === "null") {
    let child = { name: obj.groupName, children: [] };
    rootEle.children.push(child);
  } else {
    findNode(rootEle, obj);
  }
});

function findNode(ele, obj) {
  if (ele.name === obj.parentGroup) {
    let child = { name: obj.groupName, children: [] };
    ele.children.push(child);
    return true;
  } else {
    const c = ele.children.length;
    if (c > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; c > i; i++) {
        const found = findNode(ele.children[i], obj);
        if (found) break;
      }
    }
  }
}

const finalArr = rootEle.children;
```

Now `finalArr` looks like this:

```js
[
  { "name": "Unassigned", "children": [] },
  {
    "name": "P1",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "C1",
        "children": [
          { "name": "K1", "children": [] },
          { "name": "K2", "children": [] }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "C2",
        "children": [
          { "name": "A2", "children": [] },
          { "name": "A1", "children": [] }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  { "name": "F1", "children": [] },
  {
    "name": "P2",
    "children": [
      { "name": "G1", "children": [
          { "name": "GG1", "children": [] }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  { "name": "P3", "children": [] }
]
```

Comment: Yes this finalArr is missing the child node under 'P1', if you notice the 'inputs' array, there is an element {
        "id": "614447da152f69c3c1d52f34",
        "groupName": "C1",
        "parentGroup": "P1"
      }, so with this in place , the 'P1' should have 'C1' just like how the 'C2' is present under P1

Comment: Hi @Lisa, I didn't realize that C1 was missing. I've added an EDIT section to the answer where I believe the code is now producing the correct result.

Comment: Hi @Jens Ravn Jensen, sincere thanks for the answer, but i notice the nested children 'C1' too has two children which are 'K1' and 'K2' .The same with 'C2', has 'A1' and 'A2', with this solution, i could get only 1 child

Comment: Hi again @Lisa, I missed that. It was because of the order of the inputs. When we try to findNode for A2 we haven't yet added its parent C2 to the tree structure. I've added a sort by parentGroup section so that the inputs will be order from ancestor to descendent  before we call findNode.

Comment: Thanks again, @Jens Ravn Jensen, with the updated logic, the last object in the given 'inputs' array is being missed, here 'GGG1' is missing, so i added one dummy element  
let dummyEle = {
  "id": "614447da152f69c3c1d52f44",
  "groupName": "",
  "parentGroup": ""
   }
  result.body.push(dummyEle);, then proceed with the logic u shared, it worked, thanks again for the solution.

Comment: Hi @Jens Ravn Jensen, this  algorithm works with n square complexity, can u provide a better solution , the while loop will run for more than 100k times if the 'inputs' count is 10k , max = 10 * 10 = 100k times.

Comment: Hi @Lisa, good to hear from you again. Can you accept my answer if it solved your initial problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution?

Comment: Thanks @Lisa. When creating the tree structure initially we have to traverse all the elements to create the complete tree. But if a parent node is collapsed we can skip its children and only add them once the parent node is expanded. That would speed up the initial render. I'm assuming the problem is that some UI interaction is slow - such as the initial render, expanding a node or selecting a checkbox. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes UI interaction is slow while loading 7k records , in such case the value of max is becoming  7k * 7k , which is looping for 49k times

Answer (score 0):

You could take a standard algorithm for getting a tree with given data

```js
const
    getTree = (data, id, parent, root, fn = o => o) => {
      var t = {};
      data.forEach(o => ((t[o[parent]] ??= {}).children ??= []).push(Object.assign(t[o[id]] = t[o[id]] || {}, fn(o))));
      return t[root].children;
    },
    data = [{ id: "614344d9d9c21c0001e6af2e", groupName: "Unassigned", parentGroup: "null" }, { id: "614447da152f69c3c1d52f2e", groupName: "P1", parentGroup: "null" }, { id: "614447da152f69c3c1d52f38", groupName: "K1", parentGroup: "C1" }, { id: "614447da152f69c3c1d52f3e", groupName: "A2", parentGroup: "C2" }, { id: "614447da152f69c3c1d52f40", groupName: "G1", parentGroup: "P2" }, { id: "614447da152f69c3c1d52f46", groupName: "F1", parentGroup: "null" }, { id: "614447da152f69c3c1d52f30", groupName: "P2", parentGroup: "null" }, { id: "614447da152f69c3c1d52f36", groupName: "C2", parentGroup: "P1" }, { id: "614447da152f69c3c1d52f3c", groupName: "A1", parentGroup: "C2" }, { id: "614447da152f69c3c1d52f34", groupName: "C1", parentGroup: "P1" }, { id: "614447da152f69c3c1d52f32", groupName: "P3", parentGroup: "null" }, { id: "614447da152f69c3c1d52f3a", groupName: "K2", parentGroup: "C1" }, { id: "614447da152f69c3c1d52f42", groupName: "GG1", parentGroup: "G1" }, { id: "614447da152f69c3c1d52f44", groupName: "GGG1", parentGroup: "GG1" }],
    tree = getTree(data, 'groupName', 'parentGroup', null, ({ groupName: name }) => ({ name }));

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution, but i was trying to get a final array of format something like this 
[{name:'p1',children:[{name:'c1':children:[]}]},{name:'F1',children:[]},{name:'P3', children:[]}]